# How to Filter a DataView by another datatable row attribute

Tags: c#, datatable, dataview

I have 2 methods that I do not have any control over.

One returns me all dates with needed unique code(one of the row column `row[code]`) as `DataView`.

```
 DataView allDatesWithCode= portal.GetAllDatesWithCode();
```

And another method returns me only available dates but without the code.

```
DataTable availableDates = portal.GetAvailableDates();
```

Both **allDatesWithCode** and **availaleDates** has a common date column (`row[date]`).

How can I filter `allDatesWithCode` with `availableDates` to have only available dates with code?

```
DataView availableDatesWithCode = allDatesWithCode // (filtered by available date).
```

And If I had control over the `portal.GetAllDatesWithCode()` and `portal.GetAllDatesWithCode` would it make it better to have both as `DataTable` or `DataView`?
[image]

Comment: And do allDatesWithCode have any column of date ?

Comment: yes there is a column date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LINQ to join the two collections on the common field. This will give you a projection that contains all 3 fields (1 field of the DataTable and 2 fields of the DataView) for only the rows that exist in both collections (as you are joining them). You can then use `Select` to project this further to have only 2 fields. An example would be:

```
var res = (
              from dtr in DT.AsEnumerable()
              join DataRowView dvr in allDatesWithCode on dtr["date"] equals dvr["date"]
              select new {Date = dtr.Field<DateTime>("date"), Code = ((DataRowView)dvr).Row.Field<string>("code") }
          ).ToArray();
```

`res` is now an array of anonymous type objects (for all rows that exist in both collections). Each anonymous object has `Date` and `Code` properties. You can create you own type for storing the results as well.

Comment: What is DT in the first line? Could you please check the code again?

Comment: DT is your DataTable (pronounce it, Dee... Tee... :)). I have updated the code.

Comment: Just copy and paste your code. It doesnt seems ok. Please see teh screenshot above. :)

Comment: @akdurmus: Sorry, I coded that thing in VB.NET and then hand-converted it to C# on this page. I have corrected it now.

Comment: Thanks A lot now seems working fine. But return type is not DataView anymore as you say to ToArray. Basically this doesnt filter the allDatesWithCode. it generates a new array with result. Is that correct? If yes how to convert this array result back to DataView?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create a [`RowFilter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for your `DataView`:

```
StringBuilder RowFilter = new StringBuilder("date IN(");
foreach(DataRow dr in availaleDates.Rows) {
    RowFilter.Append(dr["date"].ToString()).Append(",");
}
allDatesWithCode.RowFilter = RowFilter.ToString().TrimEnd(',') +")";
```

If you had control over those methods then I suggest returning a `DataTable` and not a `DataView`, and also create a new method that will give you only the rows you need in the first place.

Comment: This also works but using linq seems better and faster. Thanks